# ggplot2 - change line width in function graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

Say I have function like:

```
quad <- function(x)
{
    return (x^2)
}
```

That I plot using `ggplot`:

```
plot <- ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0,4)), aes(x = x)) +
        stat_function(fun = quad)
```

So far, so good, but the line is really thin. I thus add some specific geometry to the line:

```
plot + geom_line(size=2)
```

But it returns this error:

> Error: geom_line requires the following missing aesthetics: y

How can I manipulate line geometry in this type of graphs?

Comment: You need `stat_function(fun = quad, size = 2)`.

Answer (score 2):

After playing around a while I found out that an argument named `size` can be passed into `stat_function`. It has the same effect as `gem_line`:

```
plot <- ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0,4)), aes(x = x)) +
        stat_function(fun = quad, size=1.5)
```